# Word Add-in Manifest file

Tags: manifest

I am trying to upload a manifest file for a Word Add-in and i keep getting error - `"no supported office products"` detected when my manifest contains

```
<Host Name="Document" />
```

If I change it to "Workbook" or "Database" it passes the test...

If I delete the section it passes for all of these:

```
Access Online
Excel 2013 or later
Excel 2016 for Mac
Excel 2016 or later
Excel Online
Excel for iPad
OneNote Online
PowerPoint 2013 or later
PowerPoint 2016 for Mac
PowerPoint 2016 or later
PowerPoint Online
PowerPoint for iPad
```

BUT not Word.... is VSTO ContentApp Word Add-in supported?

Where can i find a Word Add-in manifest example?

Thank you!

Comment: According to this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability

A Word Content App is no longer an option...